# How can i get spring-boot main-class package name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to make a spring-boot starter,so i need to get package name of application main-class.
How can i get it? 
Sometimes,you can use listener for spring boot,but it must configure in application.properties.

Comment: Why do you want to get it? It's not typically useful for a starter.

Comment: Because i want't to scan some differential class.  In order to skip other jars,i need to know main-class and find classes from here!

Comment: Differential class?

Comment: Such as some class have a annotation,or implement a interface...

Comment: And why is that relevant to what you're trying to do? You're asking a vague question and not explaining what you're trying to get done.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages;    
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

AutoConfigurationPackages.get(context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory())
```

Answer (score 0):

By this method, you can get the package of you current class.

`MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getPackage().getName()`

Comment: Thank you for you answer!But i want to know the main-class of spring-boot,how can i get it ?or search all jars even does not need those jars if can't   get it bo be start slow.

Comment: What do you mean of spring boot main-class? Spring boot project is a mess of jars, If you want to know is some class is load to your class loader, you can use @ConditionalOnBean or @ConditionalOnMissingBean(TheClassYouWantToKnow.class). more detail [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-bean-conditions)

Comment: jie, did you ever figure out how to do this? I am in similar need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that the main class will problably be annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and search for that class in the Spring Context. Implementing something like:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationFinder {

  @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;

  public String findBootClass() {
    Map<String, Object> candidates = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(SpringBootApplication.class);
    return candidates.isEmpty() ? null : candidates.values().toArray()[0].getClass();
  }
}
```

Once you jave the class name you can string slice it to extract the package.